# Connection string from web.config does not get read

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework, web-config, connection-string

Following is the architecture of my MVC application that is built using WCF service and EF:

> MVC application >> WCF Service >> Business Logic Layer >> Data access layer >> Data Store

I have created `MyDbContext` in *Data Access layer*, and it's interacting with the database.

I have created a connection string in `web.config` file of MVC application with the name `MyDbContext`. I believe this should work, but instead it is trying to create a new database on my sql server. What can be the reason? Or if I am missing anything?

If I put the connection string in `web.config` of WCF service, it works fine. but I believe this should be part of MVC application only, and WCF shouldn't be limited to using this `connectionstring` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WCF service to access business layer and data access layer your ASP.NET MVC application should not access the database directly - it should even don't know about database existence at all. That is the reason why you are using WCF service, isn't it? Otherwise you can delete whole your WCF service layer and call the business layer directly from ASP.NET MVC.

Connection string is not automatically transferred from MVC application through WCF call. The correct solution is to define connection string in WCF application because it is the tier where the database is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the WCF service is hosted in the same container which is also hosting the data access layer then it is entirely reasonable to configure it with the correct connection string.

Why would you not want to do this?